# How ca I use an Image for entire application without downloading again

Tags: android, bitmap

In my Android application I have to fetch some images from the server and show them.Same image is shown in some of the pages.Now I am downloading the same image in each page and getting out of memory error.How can I reuse the one that I have downloaded earlier in each page

Comment: try to cache your images in your apps cache directory, or on sdcard folder!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Android Query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/), and then [Image Loading](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading) in particular. It's really easy and performs well.